# Sort items in a QListWidget by their checked state

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Is there an easy way to have a QListWidget first display all checked items it holds and then all un-checked ones, with both blocks sorted alphabetically? So that a newly checked item is automatically put to the "checked" block at the correct place and vice versa?

Thanks for all advices :-)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is probably to create your own [QListWidgetItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem.html)-derived class, with an alternative implementation of less-than operator. I.e., something along the lines of:

```
class MyQListWidgetItem : public QListWidgetItem {
    public:
        // TODO: provide implementation of constructors

        virtual bool operator< (const QListWidgetItem & other) const {
            // if check state differs, use the difference for comparison
            if(checkState() != other.checkState())
                // Qt::Checked = 2 and Qt::Unchecked = 0  ->  to get checked items first,
                //   we have to "revert" the comparison operation
                return checkState() > other.checkState();

            // otherwise just return the comparison result from the base class
            return QListWidgetItem::operator < (other);
        }
}
```

Then just use this new item class for inserting all new items into your list, and it should end up ordered as you need it.

To make sure the list is sorted even after the user changes a state of an item, you should also create a slot on your list that runs [`QListWidget::sortItems()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#sortItems) whenever [`QListWidget::itemChanged()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#itemChanged) is triggered.